# Equivalent resistances in differential amplifier equation

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

When we simplify this differential amplifier and have equations for Va and Vb, then equate them together to write the expression for Vout. How come it is assumed that R2 = R1 and R4 = R3?
For example here the equation would be: [image]

But using R2 = R1 and R4 = R3 we get the more simplified form:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary that the resistors are equal, but it is usually convenient and often the reasons for choosing a particular value for one set also apply to the other set.

Usually in a differential amplifier you want R2/R1 = R4/R3. R2 and R4 may be chosen for loading on V2, or perhaps current consumption or leakage current concerns. Similar considerations may apply to R1 & R3, leading to similar choices.

Note also that if V1==V2, the input current loading for each is the same if the ratios are chosen as above.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to emphasize this: -

[image]

It's important because when the resistor values are equal: -
$$\color{red}{\text{The input impedance into both input nodes } (V_1 \text{ and } V_2) \text{ are equal}}$$

This is then called a **balanced** input differential amplifier and is used in many applications for the cancellation of noise that might be injected onto a cable that conveys a **balanced** signal.

This makes a differential amplifier truly a useful circuit in many applications. If the input impedances are unequal then the circuit has limited use.

Comment: To put it in another terms: unbalanced differential amplifiers have an bad CMRR when being attached to balanced sources.

Comment: @Sascha correct.